# Angular 5 One list Colomn data Push another List

Tags: angular

I am creating a static list

for example

```
ListA=[{ Id: 1, Name: "Tawaf" } , 
  { Id: 2, Name: "Way to umra" },{Id: 3, Name: "Select" }]
```

Another

```
ListB=[]
```

Here ListB Column Name is SlNo and CustomerName

How to push Columns data  of ListA to ListB using angular 5 Componets.ts when data type of arrays are different?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Habeeb! Please format your question using the formatting tools and try to be more specific. Also, try to include the code you have right now, and ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map and achieve

```
this.ListB = this.ListA.map((data) => {
    return {'SlNo': data.Id, 'CustomerName': data.Name};
  });
```

Comment: Sorry ,I expect ListA column location data Bind to ListB.Here List A ColumnName Is Sl No,Customer Name So columnname is space also.In case how to bind List A column data to List B .using location data